# Altering CSS value with Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a chat box for my website.

```
<div class="chat_box1">
<div id="chat_box_bar">
    <p>(SOME PHP CODE HERE)</p>
        <p id="close_chat" onclick="close_chat_box(1)">X</p>

</div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if I set the display to "none", and could change it to "block" only when clicked on some text. As:

```
<li onclick='display_chat_box(chat_box_number(),"kamal@kamal.com")'>KAMAL</li>
```

The javascript function:

```
function display_chat_box(y,email)
{
   switch (y)
   {
        case 1:
        {
           alert("hi");
           document.getElementsByClass("chat_box1")[0].style.display="block";
        }
        case 2:
        {
           document.getElementsByClass("chat_box2")[0].style.display="block";
        }
        case 3:
        {
           document.getElementsByClass("chat_box3")[0].style.display="block";
        }
    }
}
```

I have inserted the alert code in 1st case in order to check if the code inside the scope works, and it does as the alert box pops when I run the webpage.

The problem: The display property does not change to "block" from "none". Don't know why, but it somehow worked on another PC I was working on earlier.

The variable 'y' gets its value from this function:

```
function chat_box_number()
{
    if(n==3)
        n=0;
    n++;
    return n;
}
```

Here's the CSS code:

```
.chat_box1,.chat_box2,.chat_box3
{
   display: none;
   width: 20%;
   position: fixed;
   bottom:0;
   margin-right: 10px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: thin;
   height:30%;
   font-family: comic sans ms;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Where have you defined the variable "n"

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Does your browser support getElementsByClass ???

Comment: @reinder Yeah, initial value of n is 0. Sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: @DotNETNinja I'm sorry I do not have an IDE currently. Usind the notepad instead. How am I supposed to debug?

Comment: You don't need an IDE to debug JS, HTML, CSS. You just need browser with developer tools like Google Chrome, Opera or IE or Firefox with Firebug plugin installed.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal - I'm using Google Chrome, and it did work in the previous Computer that I had been using. Don't know the problem with this one. I guess it supports well if it worked earlier!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice untill now but I don't think your switch statement is valid javascript

When writing a case you should do it like the following:

```
case 1:
   whatever_you_want_to_do();
   break;
```

instead of

```
case 1:
{
   whatever_you_want_to_do();
}
```

And the right function to use is `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementsByClass`

Comment: It's valid JavaScript. You can group statements into a block anywhere: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: But you'd still have to "break".

Comment: Oops! Yeah, that's obvious now that you pointed it out. :-) Good catch.

Comment: Holy Molyyy! How could I ever forget the 'break'!! Damn I should punch myself! Thanks a lot. And yeah, it should be ClassName instead of Class.. Works fine now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

what if you set?...

```
whatever.style.display="block !important";
```